# MultiValueDictKeyError en / sistemacaja / comprar_do

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

ayuda porque del error cuando ejecuto python manage.py runserver y no reconoce a mis productos.
views.py

```
def comprar(request):

    productos = literal_eval(request.POST["productos"])
    pago      = literal_eval(request.POST["pago"])

    try:
        usr = get_object_or_404(Usuario, cedula = request.POST["cliente"])
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        n_c = literal_eval(request.POST["nuevo_cliente"])
        usr = Usuario(  nombre = n_c["nombre"],
                        cedula = n_c["cedula"],
                        carnet = n_c["carnet"],
                        saldo  = 0,
                        fecha  = datetime.now(),
                        tipo   = 'C')
    usr.save()
    f = Factura( usuario = usr, fecha = datetime.now())
    f.save()

    for d in productos:
        prod = get_object_or_404(Producto, nombre = d["nombre"])

        pv = VentaProducto(producto = prod, factura = f, cantidad = d["cantidad"], precio = prod.precio_obj())
        pv.save()

        prod.ventas   += 1
        prod.cantidad -= pv.cantidad
        prod.save()

    e = Decimal(pago['efectivo'])
    s = Decimal(pago['saldo'])

    if(e > 0):
        m1 = MovimientoVentas(factura = f, tipo = 'E', cantidad =  e)
        m1.save()

    if(s > 0):
        m1 = MovimientoVentas(factura = f, tipo = 'S', cantidad = s)
        m1.save()
        usr.saldo -= s

    usr.save()

    return redirect(reverse('ventas_app.views.compra_ok'))
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\us\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\us\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\us\sistema_ventas_ceic_master\ventas_app\views.py", line 517, in comprar
    productos = literal_eval(request.POST["productos"])
  File "C:\us\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 301, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'productos'"
[17/Nov/2018 17:00:47] "GET /sistemacaja/comprar_do HTTP/1.1" 500 92107
```

Comment: El error sucede al evaluar `request.POST["productos"]` y por tanto eso significa que entre los datos del POST no aparece `"productos"`. Supongo que ese POST te llega a través de un FORM, así que deberás revisar éste a ver si realmente tiene el campo "productos".

Comment: verifique mi Form y si es POST, tambien añadi get, **request.POST.get["productos"]**  tambien me sale error otra sugerencia, que necesita **El objeto 'instancemethod' no tiene atributo '__getitem__'**

Comment: Lo que acabas de intentar tendría que haber sido `request.POST.get("productos")`, es decir, con paréntesis, pues `.get()` es un método. No obstante, para lo que sirve ese método es para evitar la excepción, ya que si le pides una clave que no está (como `"productos"`) en lugar de una excepción te devolverá `None`, pero probablemente tu código rompa más adelante por culpa de ese `None`. Lo que tendrías que averiguar es por qué no existe la clave `"productos"`, y para ello deberás mirar en el HTML del formulario.

Comment: cambien mi codigo como me dice **request.POST.get("productos")**  pero me sale otro error **raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string** alguna otra ayuda por favor

Comment: si relees mi anterior comentario verás que te lo advertí. Si usas `get()` pero la clave no existe, te devolverá `None` y te dará error más adelante. **Tienes que mirar tu FORM** (en el HTML que lo crea, o incluso en el navegador) a ver por qué no tiene el campo "productos". El error está en el formulario y no en el python que lo procesa. Yo ya no sé cómo ayudarte más.

Comment: deberias incluir tu codigo del form que envias hacia la vista...!!

Comment: elimine **literal_eval**, acepto y paso a la siguiente linea de código que también existe error, para reemplazar **literal_eval** use *ast.literal_eval**  lo malo es que obtengo el mismo error algo para reemplazarlo en python 2.7